# Trouble with Index Out of Range Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a textbox for a small game and I've run into an issue. I'm using drawString, which doesn't support \n so I've made an array of strings for multiple lines like so. Also, there is a global int called lettersShown that will be important later.

```
int lettersShown = 0;
String[] result = new String[] {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "};
```

In the constructor of the class, I then created a random event containing an array of 8 strings(Sorry if this is long and poorly formatted, its just for testing purposes.)

```
travel.add(new Event(this, new String[]{"You walk along a winding dirt 
road,", "exposed to the scorching of the sun.",
            "Every so often, you pass the remains", "of blasted homes 
and dilapidated", "hovels. The air is especially arid", 
            "today, and by the time the sun drifts", "down into the horizon 
you find", "yourself parched."}, -20,0,0,0));
```

So after I did that, I created a method to draw each line in order.

```
public void drawText( int x, int y, Graphics g) {   

    for(int i = 0; i <result.length; i++) {
        g.drawString(result[i].substring(0, lettersShown), x, y);
        if(result[i].length() > lettersShown) {
            lettersShown++; 
    }
        //lettersShown = 0;
        y+=15;

    }
}
```

This method works perfectly for any arrays that only have one string, such as this one:

```
travel.add(new Event(this, new String[] {"You traveled to a new city"}, 
0,0,0,0));
```

However, the second it starts to render an event with multiple lines, I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:23
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at mains.EventManager.drawText(EventManager.java:149)
at mains.Game.render(Game.java:185)
at mains.Game.run(Game.java:87)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've been trying so many things to fix this seemingly small issue and I'd rather not resort to just having a ton of strings and drawing each of them one at a time so any guidance or anyone who can identify the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Next, try this one: If you wanted to display the strings "Hello" "You", what substring of "You" would you try to form when `lettersShown = 4`?

Comment: Letters shown would never reach 4 because "You" only has three characters. Is lettersShown one more than its supposed to be?

Comment: Where are you setting lettersShown back to 0?

Comment: These strings are supposed to appear when you press one of four buttons so when you press the buttons, the lettersShown is reset to 0.

Comment: Heres an example .   public String[] scavenge() {
  lettersShown=0;
  int rand = (int)(Math.random()*5);

  if(sustenance < 50) {
   rand = (int)(Math.random()*scavenge.size());
  }


  result =  scavenge.get(rand).getResult();
  scavenge.get(rand).eventEffect();
  sustenance-=5;
  exhaustion+=5;
  carryOver = 5 - (24-hours);
  hours+=5;


  return result;

 }

Comment: `lettersShown` does reach 4, because in the case of "Hello" "You", `lettersShown` can grow up to the longest length of the strings, so in this case, 5. What is the expected behaviour? Do you want each line to display character by character simultaneously, or do you want to display the text starting from the top, and moving line by line, character by character to render more?

Comment: My intention was to have it render character by character and line by line rather than simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this method one step at a time:

```
public void drawText( int x, int y, Graphics g) {   

    for(int i = 0; i <result.length; i++) {
        g.drawString(result[i].substring(0, lettersShown), x, y);
        if(result[i].length() > lettersShown) {
            lettersShown++; 
    }
        //lettersShown = 0;
        y+=15;

    }
}
```

Say `result = ["Hello", "You"]` and we're at `lettersShown = 3`, `i = 0`:

1. `g.drawString(result[i].substring(0, lettersShown), x, y);`

   will print `"Hello".substring(0, 3)`, ie. "Hel" - so far so good.
2. `if(result[i].length() > lettersShown)`

   well, `"Hello"` has length 5 > 3, so this test passes.
3. `lettersShown++;` So now `lettersShown = 4`
4. `}` We hit the end of our loop, so we increment `i` to 1 and start again.
5. `g.drawString(result[i].substring(0, lettersShown), x, y);`

   will try to print the first `lettersShown = 4` letters of `result[1] = "You"`... uh oh.

   "You" has only 3 letters, but we're trying to get a substring of length 4 out of it! Kaboom.

So: you need to keep track of how many letters *of the current string* you want to print.

```
public void drawText( int x, int y, Graphics g) {
    // Let's show one more letter than we did last time.
    lettersShown++;

    int lettersRemaining = lettersShown;

    for(int i = 0; i <result.length && lettersRemaining > 0; i++) {

        // Don't try to take more letters than we have!
        int substringLength = Math.min(lettersRemaining, result[i].length());

        g.drawString(result[i].substring(0, substringLength), x, y);

        // Proceed to next line
        // Update our remaining letter count & vertical position.
        lettersRemaining -= result[i].length();        
        y+=15;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I just saw this, tried to do something similar to it and it ended up working. Thank you so much for the patience and advice.

Comment: Don't forget to hit the Accept checkmark to mark the issue as resolved.